# Help making an answer page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make this:

[image]

So far this is what I got:

[image]

I have no idea what to do next, any suggestions? I'm  using Linux.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \foreach [count=\i] \x in {a,b,c,d}
          \foreach \y in {32,...,1}
          { \pgfmathsetmacro\result{int(33 - \y)}
            \node at (0,0.5*\y) {\result};
            \draw (0.5*\i,0.5*\y) circle (0.2cm);
            \node[circle] at (0.5*\i,0.5*\y) {\x};
          }
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Are asking about how to compile the file or how to add further coding?  In the first instance just run `pdflatex` on the above `file.tex` and it will produce `file.pdf`.

Comment: how to add futher coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step towards to final result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}]
        \foreach \row in {1,2,...,32}{
            \foreach \col [evaluate=\col as \n using {int((\col-1)*32+\row)}] in {1,2,...,4}
            {
                \node (\n) at (3.5*\col,-0.6*\row) {\n};
          \foreach [count=\nx] \x in {A,B,C,D,E}
          {
            \node[circle, draw, minimum size=5mm, inner sep=2pt] at (3.5*\col+0.55*\nx,-0.6*\row) (\n-\x) {\x};
          }
        }}
        \foreach \i in {16,28,40,52,64,80,92,104,116}
        \draw (\i.west|-\i-E.south)--(\i-E.south-|\i-E.east);
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a second step:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={2cm,2cm},hmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}\sffamily
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
ADMINISTRACIÓN FEDERAL DE SERVICIOS EDUCATIVOS EN EL D.F.\\
SUBDIRECCIÓN DE ESCUELAS SECUNDARIAS TÉCNICAS EN EL D.F.\\
ESCUELA SECUNDARIA TÉCNICA No. \rule[-1pt]{2cm}{1pt}\\
Examen de simulación para la toma de decisions\\[3mm]

Nombre:\rule[-1pt]{8.5cm}{1pt}Grupo:\rule[-1pt]{1cm}{1pt}Turno:\rule[-1pt]{2cm}{1pt}\\[2mm]

\begin{tabular}{rll}
Instrucciones & Llena completamente los círculos. & Usa sólo lápiz del 2 1/2.\\
              & Si te equivocas borra completamente. & No uses pluma ni marcador \\
              & No hagas ninguna marca fuera de los círculos & Revisa tu examen antes de entregarlo
\end{tabular}\\[2mm]

\framebox[\textwidth]{HOJA ÚNICA DE RESPUESTAS PARA EL TERCER EXAMEN DE SIMULACIÓN}\\[3mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base, minimum height=5mm, font=\sffamily},
        number/.style={text width=width("128"), align=right},
        letter/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, draw}]
      \foreach \i [count=\ni,
            evaluate=\i as \col using {int((\i-1)/32)},
            evaluate=\i as \row using {int(mod((\i-1),32))}] in {1,2,...,128}
            {
             \node[number] (\ni) at (4*\col,-0.6*\row) {\ni};
                \foreach [count=\nx from 0] \x in {A,B,C,D,E}
                    \node[letter] at (4*\col+0.7+0.55*\nx,-0.6*\row) (\ni-\x) {\x};
            }
        \foreach \i in {16,28,40,52,64,80,92,104,116}
            \draw (\i.south west)--(\i.south-|\i-E.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice ! I think it would be a good idea to have `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}]`.

Comment: @marsupilam You're probably right, but I don't see any difference using capital letters except that numbers are a little bit lower positioned.

Comment: Excelent answer! You really help me, for the rest I was thinkig of using a `minipage` or use the `exam` class, what do you think?

Comment: @LuisVictoria try with the updated answer